# How to keep running electron app in background when pc is kept sleep?

Tags: electron

I want to build an electron app which should be running in background even when pc is kept on sleep mode. I have used electron's `powerSaveBlocker` according to [this](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/power-save-blocker) doc and I added those lines in my `main.js` file like this:

```
...
const {app, BrowserWindow, Tray, Menu, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const { powerSaveBlocker } = require('electron');

const id = powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-app-suspension');
console.log(powerSaveBlocker.isStarted(id));

let win;
...
```

But this isn't working for me. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> powerSaveBlocker API

together with

> powerMonitor API

**Note:** call it when the app is ready.

```
app.on("ready", () => {
    createWindow();
    powerMonitor.on("lock-screen", () => {
      powerSaveBlocker.start("prevent-display-sleep");
    });
    powerMonitor.on("suspend", () => {
      powerSaveBlocker.start("prevent-app-suspension");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was testing 'prevent-display-sleep' and 'prevent-app-suspension'.

First - when pc at sleep mode you can't run anything!

Your target is prevent turning to sleep mode by adding only:
`powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-app-suspension');`

If you going to add also `powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-display-sleep');`
it won't work according to [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-save-blocker)